# wxpython get currently selected notebook tab label (not index)

Tags: python, wxpython

I have an EVT_NOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGED function to alert me when the tab changes, but I can only get it to tell me the index of the notebook tab:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_NOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGED, self.eventntbkParameters, self.ntbkParameters)
```

&

```
page = self.ntbk.GetSelection()
print page
```

I don't think this it is very safe to determine the which tab is selected in this way in case an extra tab is added in the future, reshuffling the indices.
Is it possible to get the label of the tab instead?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `ntbk.GetPageText(evt.GetSelection())`.

```
class MyNotebook(AuiNotebook):
  def __init__(self, parent, id, *args, **kwds): #@ReservedAssignment
    AuiNotebook.__init__(self, parent, id, *args,
      style = NO_BORDER | AUI_NB_CLOSE_ON_ALL_TABS | AUI_NB_TAB_SPLIT, **kwds)

    self._tabs = ['Jobs', 'Devices', 'Actions', 'Transforms']

    self.Bind(EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_PAGE_CLOSE, self.OnPageClosed)

  def OnPageClosed(self, evt):
    page = self.GetPageText(evt.GetSelection())
```